# Stopping My Burning Tongue

Tags: food, comfort

People have always claimed that they can completely negate the effects of eating something too spicy, which results in "burning" your tongue, where people will either drink cold water or cold milk.

I have tried and tried to completely negate the effects of eating something too spicy but to no avail. Many people recommend drinking cold milk. It does help for like three seconds, then my tongue starts to "burn" again. Water definitely doesn't help and running around in circles and screaming at the top of my lungs won't help. It will only help raise the noise pollution...

So what is the best possible way to completely (or as much a possible) stop your tongue from burning due to eating something too spicy? No, it is not a duplicate because I'm only talking about the tongue, excluding the cheeks and the rest of the mouth.

Comment: Beside mixing the food with a dairy product or other buffer. I really can't think of a good solution, not to say there isn't one though :)

Comment: Rinse your mouth with that cold milk and hold it a bit (In case of oily spices  such as peppers etc.)

Comment: lifehacker.com once said hydrogen peroxide does the trick (just don't swallow)

Comment: I've never found a solution, other than just not eating hot spices in the first place. Spicy's fine, its hot and spicy my tongue can't cope with...

Answer (score 2):

'Curd' does the magic. Cover your entire tongue using chilled curd, as it reduces the burning sensation for moment and if you repeat this couple of times with fresh curd, that sensation disappears easily. I did this couple of times at my grandma's house.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best ways I have found for easing the effect of Capsaicin (the active component of chili peppers) exposure is NOT by drinking water (all this does is spread the oils around the mouth more which will make the burning sensation worse)

What works for me is actually a spoonful (teaspoon NOT tablespoon) of granulated cane sugar.

Some background to why this works: 
The [Scoville scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoville_scale) uses a sugar solution in order to dilute the capsaicin solution until the heat is no longer detected.

Therefore it stands to reason that sugar (or a sugar syrup) will be helpful in negating the effects when your mouth is burning.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on base chemistry of the spicy.

- Oil Based
- Water Based

Oil based, chili peppers and such, really require a soluble liquid to wash them off the surface of your tongue.  Tequila and beer come to mind because the alcohol is soluble and will make it go away.

Water based spicy, wasabe, is water soluble.  Water will do the trick.

Comment: I'm under 21 so no tequila or beer for me...